# How can I make a menu at the bottom of a view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I wanted to I wanted to create a menu at the bottom of my apps similar to this

[image]

The menu button is at the bottom of the layout, and when you click on it, it could expand to a list of items. How can I achieve this menu effect? I have looked up action bar in Android, sadly it's only placed at the top. How can I customize it to my purpose?

A xml sketch would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a custom view on the bottom of the page, try using `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Your Contents" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/transparent_white"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/x" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5.6 miles" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/overflow" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To handle the overflow-menu you can use `PopupMenu` like this:

```
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, view);
        popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.my_menu);
        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {...});
        popupMenu.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split your action bar to see it in the bottom :

In your manifest :

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then, the action bar will be displayed at bottom.

More informations here : [Action Bar - Using split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar)